# Obj-C UIImageView not showing image from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am doing a little self learning with Obj-c and interested in making a flash card application. I have an NSArray with objects with 5 images in the array. When the user presses the forward button I am trying to get my UIImageView to show the next image in the array. I get Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=2,address=0x0) on the line where I get an image from my array. Here is my current header and implementation file.

```
@interface WhoAmIViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *flashcardviewer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *aryFlashcards;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger *int_counter;
@end


@implementation WhoAmIViewController
@synthesize aryFlashcards;
@synthesize flashcardviewer;
@synthesize int_counter;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    aryFlashcards = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"shot_1"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"shot_2"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"shot_3"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"shot_4"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"shot_5"],
                                         nil];
    int_counter = 0;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//back button
- (IBAction)btn_back:(UIButton *)sender {
}

//forward button
- (IBAction)btn_forward:(UIButton *)sender
{


    flashcardviewer = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    UIImage *flashcard_next = [UIImage imageNamed:[aryFlashcards objectAtIndex:*(int_counter)]]; //This is where Xcode throws me an error. 
    flashcardviewer.image = flashcard_next;
    int_counter++;


}

//random button
- (IBAction)btn_random:(UIButton *)sender
    {

}
```

Comment: Ditch this line `flashcardviewer = [[UIImageView alloc]init];`. It's effectively throwing out your IBOutlet.

Comment: geez, this tiny code-fragment is full of logical errors! it hard to start telling you how you have to fix it...

Comment: it is needless to say that the `aryFlashcards` has already the `UIImage` objects (not their names!), so `UIImage * flashcard_next = [aryFlashcards objectAtIndex:*int_counter];` would be the proper way to access to the desired image... the `NSUInteger *int_counter` is a pointer and you are increasing the pointer like `int_counter++`...? what do you like to achieve with it? increase the value instead like `(*int_counter)++;` or something...

Comment: why do you init every time a new `flashcardviewer` object? why don't you use the previously inited one? or at least why don't you add the new instance as a subview to the current view? it would be still messy but at least it would do something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
//Declare int_counter like this
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger int_counter;

//Set btn_forward: this way
- (IBAction)btn_forward:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //Avoid possible app crash with a if condition 
    if (int_counter < flashcard_next.count) {
        UIImage *flashcard_next = [aryFlashcards objectAtIndex:int_counter];
        flashcardviewer.image = flashcard_next;
        int_counter++;
    } else {
        NSLog (@"No more cards");
    }
}
```

You can learn more about `NSInteger` [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/nsnumber-and-nsinteger.html).

Comment: I really liked your answer because it also showed how to do a bit more. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You made int_counter a pointer instead of an NSInteger. Try

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger int_counter;
```

and

```
    UIImage *flashcard_next = [aryFlashcards objectAtIndex:int_counter];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on this line:

```
UIImage *flashcard_next = [UIImage imageNamed:[aryFlashcards objectAtIndex:*(int_counter)]];
```

You're creating a `UIImage` object and passing another `UIImage` to the method when it's expecting a `NSString`. Change this to:

```
UIImage *flashcard_next = [aryFlashcards objectAtIndex:int_counter];
```

and as mentioned in the other answer, remove the pointer to `int_counter`.

Answer (score 0):

Your iVar aryFlashcards is already instantiated with 5 images in viewDidLoad method. In your btn_forward method implementation you should replace

```
UIImage *flashcard_next = [UIImage imageNamed:[aryFlashcards objectAtIndex:*(int_counter)]];
```

With following provided *(int_counter) is less than aryFlashCards size which looks to be 5 in your example else your app will throw out of bound exception.

```
UIImage *flashcard_next = [aryFlashcards objectAtIndex:*(int_counter)];
```